# present continuous or simple in this case

Tags: continuous

When you are writing or write the address, don't forget to add:attention to xxxxxx

I think continuous would be better but can I use present continuous for a very quick action (writing xxxxx).
I know that I can write :
When  writing the address, don't forget to add to xxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

I interpret that you are asking which is better:

'When you write the address, don't forget to add to xxxxxx.'

'When writing the address, don't forget to add to xxxxxx.'

Both are natural.

Comment: so there is no difference between these two, they are interchangeable, I thought present simple was for an habitual action